# Ignore distinct clause on primary key in postgres

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, primary-key, distinct

I am a postgres newbie.
Our application has a query something like this.

```
select count(distinct pk_column) from table;

explain analyze select count(distinct pk_column) from table;
QUERY PLAN
Aggregate  (cost=35797.30..35797.31 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1251.631..1251.632 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on table  (cost=0.00..34606.24 rows=476424 width=8) (actual time=0.006..420.212 rows=477889 loops=1)
Total runtime: 1251.676 ms

Query performance improves when distinct clause on primary key column is removed.


explain analyze select count(pk_column) from table;
QUERY PLAN
Aggregate  (cost=35797.30..35797.31 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=817.994..817.995 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on table  (cost=0.00..34606.24 rows=476424 width=8) (actual time=0.006..434.674 rows=477890 loops=1)
Total runtime: 818.040 ms
```

without changing query, is it possible to tell postgres to ignore distinct clause on primary key column?

`Version: PostgreSQL 9.1.9 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`, compiled by `gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, 64-bit`

Comment: Shouldn't the primary key be distinct anyway? Why use distinct in this case?

Comment: That is so true. I don't have control over the code to change the query

Comment: But postgres should be clever enough to ignore it automatically. I don't see why this should not be possible.

Comment: it is not evident from explain output

Comment: This may not be the best example to demonstrate it, but postgres does indeed not take advantage of this. You can tell from the query plans for `SELECT DISTINCT pk_column FROM table` and `SELECT pk_column FROM table`, the former includes a sorting and uniqueification step although they are unnecessary. This is still so in 9.4, unfortunately.

Comment: @chirlu TBF the step is only unnecessary for "trivial" queries with no joins, otherwise the join may introduce duplications. That might be why pg's query optimiser never got this feature added.

Answer (score 1):

Your testing methodology appears to be flawed. Those are the same query plans, and no additional plan node is being added for the `DISTINCT`.

I think you're just seeing caching effects. Repeat each one a few times and they'll likely start to come out pretty similar.

This is really a variation of the [slow counting problem](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting) which has been largely addressed in PostgreSQL 9.2 by the addition of [index-only scans](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans). Consider upgrading.

Thanks for including your version details and the `explain analyze` output right from the start.

Comment: I did run both queries multiple times to avoid the effect of caching.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce it in 9.2 after a few runs:

```
create table t (pk_column serial primary key);
insert into t
select generate_series(1, 477890);
analyze t;

explain analyze select count(distinct pk_column) from t;
                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=8088.63..8088.64 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=210.755..210.755 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on t  (cost=0.00..6893.90 rows=477890 width=4) (actual time=0.012..28.018 rows=477890 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 210.790 ms

explain analyze select count(pk_column) from t;
                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=8088.63..8088.64 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=51.892..51.892 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on t  (cost=0.00..6893.90 rows=477890 width=4) (actual time=0.005..24.541 rows=477890 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 51.911 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain your PK column is actually a Primary Key? The EXPLAIN ANALYZE with distinct shows 477889 rows, whereas the EXPLAIN ANALYZE without the distinct is showing 477890.

Comment: \d table does show that column to be primary key. The difference in output is because a row was added to the table between the two queries.